# How to check column that contain letter and number in Talend

Tags: talend, multiplication, division, tmap, data-integration

My columns must contains **2 letter** and **4 number** like this (AV1234)

How can i check this ?

Comment: Why don't you use sql templates to do so

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sql templates as mentioned in talend documentation [here](https://help.talend.com/r/JdTBzKszzXoWvjpEJD3EBA/TDxH0u3RnBV0zc3ecpoTuA) and you can check your column that contain letter and number using regular expressions.

Use this `[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}`

Use this If you want only uppercase letters `[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}`

```
[a-zA-Z]    # Match a single character present in the list below
            # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
            # A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
  {2}       # Exactly 2 times
[0-9]       # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
  {6}       # Exactly 6 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer ! **it Works**

**My routine code:**

```
public static Boolean MyPattern(String str) {


String stringPattern = "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}"; 

boolean match = Pattern.matches(stringPattern, str);


return match ;

  }
```